# SOQL for Attachment and Case

Tags: salesforce

I have this query

```
SELECT   
    Body, BodyLength, ContentType, CreatedById, CreatedDate,
    Description, Id, Name, OwnerId, ParentId 
FROM 
    Attachment 
WHERE
    parentid IN (SELECT id FROM Case)
```

`ParentId` is the subject id in `Attachment` but I need case number (column of case) also

But there is a case number column in Case Object and I need this case number in the same query so how I can get case number from Case

Answer (score 0):

For "bottom-up" query you can read up about [polymorphic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm)

```soql
SELECT   
    Body, BodyLength, ContentType, CreatedById, CreatedDate,
    Description, Id, Name, OwnerId, ParentId, TYPEOF Parent WHEN Case THEN CaseNumber, Subject END
FROM 
    Attachment 
WHERE
    parentid IN (SELECT id FROM Case)
LIMIT 10
```

Often these things look cleaner "top-down" but in this particular scenario if you add `Body` you'll be slapped with "*Binary fields cannot be selected in join queries*" error.

```soql
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Subject,
    (SELECT Id, Name, Description, ContentType FROM Attachments)
FROM Case
LIMIT 10
```